# Add unless value would be greater than

Tags: python

I need to add to variable `start` unless the value will be greater than variable `total`. I am getting a json response with items, but can only get 250 each time I request. But I can choose where I want to start in the list in my request. So if they have 560 items, I need to request the items 250 at a time until it gets to 560. However if `start > total` it will return an error. So I have a `while` loop that adds 250 every time its passed, unless `start > total`. However the obvious flaw is that it will still add 250 even if `value` is 559. Thus an error. How would I do this?

```
start = 0
total = 560
def func1():
    global start
    global total
    while start < total:
        start+=250
        print(start)
        #somefunc()
    else:
        start = 0
        #somefunc()

func1()
```

and my output is

```
0
250
750
```

I need the output to be

```
0
250
560
```

Comment: Your output should have `500` instead of `750`.

Comment: "my output is" -- no it isn't.

Comment: changed the code to reflect the output, forgot to change where the `print` statement was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```
start = 0
total = 560
def func1():
    global start
    global total
    while start < total:
        if start > (total-250):
            start += total-start
            print(start)
        else:
            print(start)
            start+=250
            #somefunc()
    else:
        start = 0
        #somefunc()

func1()
```

This gives me the output:

```
0
250
560
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary assignment:

```
>>> s=0
>>> total=12
>>> inc=3
>>> for _ in range(10):    
...    s+=inc if s+inc<total else 0
... 
>>> s
9
```

Note: best to refactor your code to avoid the `global`